# Is the offline filtering in WinPcap thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

Using WinPcap 4.1.2, I have a need to collect all of the IP-based traffic on a given interface and then filter user-selected TCP- and UDP-based "conversations" for layer 7 processing.  Due to the simultaneous need to uniquely tag each incoming frame once, I cannot use the obvious solution of having multiple `pcap_t` devices with a unique filter for each device.  Instead, I am collecting the data with a single `pcap_t` device, tagging each frame, and then leveraging the `pcap_offline_filter` API to filter each selected "conversation" in a separate thread (i.e., X conversations will be filtered in X different threads) to take full advantage of the multi-core systems this application will be running on.

The question is simple.  Is the `pcap_offline_filter` API thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pcap_offline_filter()` has no global data that would be shared by multiple instances, so, as long as you're not modifying its *arguments* in other threads (there's no reason to do so - you shouldn't, for example, be changing the compiled filter structure while in the middle of filtering with it, or changing the packet header or data while filtering it), it's thread-safe.

(`pcap_compile()`, however, is not itself thread-safe; it's based on a YACC parser and Lex lexical analyzer, and I don't think yacc or Bison, or Lex or Flex, generate thread-safe code by default, and the code generator also has global variables.  Just make sure you compile the filter expressions in the same thread; you can then let multiple threads *use* those expressions.  I've checked into the libpcap trunk a change to make the first argument to `pcap_offline_filter()` a `const struct bpf_program *`, to clarify that it reads but doesn't modify the filter.  That applies both to the `struct bpf_program` and to the array of `struct bpf_insns` to which that structure points.)

Comment: Thanks, Guy.  I was hoping to hear from you on this one.  ;-)